# Multiple Search Refiners in Same Category

Tags: 2010, search, fast-search

Does anyone know if there is an easy way to convert the standard SharePoint refiner pane to allow multiple refinement choices within a single category?  For example, putting a check box  next to the items so that you can select two authors, as opposed to having the remaining authors disappear when you refine by a specific one.

It doesn't seem like there is anything out of the box, but has anyone seen any easy implementations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create your own refinement web part in order to do this.

Once you click a refiner, the dataset returned does not contain the values which are now removed. In order to achieve this you will have to execute two searches. First the one without any refiners clicked, then the one where you select a refiner, then you have to merge these two sets.

And if a second refiner value is selected in an already selected category you will have to append this to the refiner you chose.

It's not that hard, but not super easy either.

Answer (score 1):

Just by extending the XSL of the Refinement Panel and adding a little javascript it is possible to select multiple Refiners via the UI:
http://theressomethingaboutsharepoint.blogspot.com/2012/02/select-multiple-refiners-via-ui-with.html